# "Cannot resolve collation conflict" even after fixing the collation

Tags: sql-server

The current database I'm using "PrimaryDatabase" has the collation "`SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`", while the "SecondaryDatabase" I'm trying to access has the collation "`Arabic_CI_AS`"

I changed the collation for the SecondaryDatabase and set it to " `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`" and made sure it has been changed as well as in its tables.

However, when i run the query below I still get collation conflict.

```
select * from [MYSERVER].[SecondaryDatabase].[dbo].[SecondaryTableName] 
where ltrim(rtrim([SecondaryTablename])) not in (select ltrim(rtrim(PrimaryFieldname))  from PrimaryTablename where PrimaryFieldName2=1)
```

Comment: You have to set the collation at field level

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Can you tell me how I can do that ?

Comment: What do you mean by `as well as in its tables`?  Changing the default database collation does not automatically change the collation of existing columns.  You'll need to either `ALTER` each column individually or rebuild each table with the new collation.

Comment: @DanGuzman I mean that for each column that collation was set to "Default Collation" so it gets set automatically

Comment: @user4612290, when the database default collation is used, it is persisted when the column is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to make your query work is to use `COLLATE` clause in order to apply a collation cast on both fields being involved in the predicate of the `WHERE` clause:

```
select * 
from [MYSERVER].[SecondaryDatabase].[dbo].[SecondaryTableName] 
where ltrim(rtrim([SecondaryFieldname])) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
      not in (select ltrim(rtrim(PrimaryFieldname)) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
              from PrimaryTablename 
              where PrimaryFieldName2 = 1)
```

The `COLLATE` clause applied to `PrimaryFieldname` might not be necessary, since this is the default collation of the corresponding database (so probably `PrimaryFieldname` already has this collation).

Another solution is to change the collation at field level, e.g.:

```
ALTER TABLE SecondaryDatabase
ALTER COLUMN SecondaryFieldname VARCHAR(50)
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS NULL
```